# Python version of ifelse for variable declaration

Tags: python, r

Is there a simple way to declare variables in Python similar to R's ifelse?

In R for example:

```
outgroup <- ifelse(politics == "Republican", 1, 0)
```

In Python, I'm doing:

```
outgroup = 0
if politics == "Republican":
    outgroup = 1
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this in Python?

Comment: **Python does not have variable declarations**.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, and I also don't see how the linked answer is a response.

Comment: I mean that if I take your question literally, there is no way because you cannot declare variables in Python because *Python doesn't have variable declarations*. In any case, the linked answer shows you Python's conditional expression syntax, which would be the closes equivalent to what you want.

Comment: So in this case: `1 if politics == "Republican else 0`